# Download all Google sheets

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to download all available sheets from Google Spreadsheet from C# with Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
I have written the following code which I got from Google developer web page but here it is only able to connect particuler sheet by its id :

UserCredential credential;

```
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(@"credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });




        // Define request parameters.
        String spreadsheetId = "1rpmT0S1Naic8wG8xok2cjNJBIgKa8t24C80muc8YVNE";// "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        String range = "Class Data!A1:B4";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
```

Is there any way to download all Sheets name and its spreadsheet id, so that my program can connect each one by one by its id and update the data ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on exactly what it is you want to do as your question is unclear i suspect due to your misunderstanding of the APIs and what they do.

- Google Sheets API is there to allow you to access the contents within a sheet.
- Google Drive API would allow you file store access to the actual sheets themselves.

So if you are for example looking to download a list of all the google sheets a user has access to you would use the Google drive api file.list method.  You could then download the file itself to your hard drive.  Or you could use the Google sheets api to look look at the continence of the files themselves.

```
var request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"
var result = request.Execute();
```

[My drive samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/FilesSample.cs)

**Directions on Google drive api**

What you need to remember is the Google drive api is a file store api. Think of it as file explorer on a windows PC. It contains all the information about the files that the user has access to. The google sheets api only has access to the data within the files that are of type pplication/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

**Fetch a list of files of type sheet**

```
var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Drive Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
            });

var request = driveService.Files.List();
request.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"
var result = request.Execute();

var fileId = result.FirstOrDefault().Id
var fileId = result.FirstOrDefault().Name
```

**Scope**

Remember to access a users data you must have permission of the user to access that data for this to work you must have requested the permission to access their drive data.  One of the following scopes should work.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata

**List All files Tutorial**

This tutorial may also help you [List All files](https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/).  You just need to add the Q parameter to list only files of a specific metatdata type.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Actually I just want to populate all Sheet names and its ID in the Dropdown list in winform C#. So when user select any sheet from dropdown and update that sheet programatically .

Comment: Then go though the Google drive api use file lists with a search on mimetype like i showed you.

Comment: Ok . I tried this but it is unable to recognize the File class method ,                                                    // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,

            });

            var request = service.Files.List();
            request.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"
            var result = request.Execute();

Comment: Ok Thanks. I looked in to the mentioned link . It is good , but unfortunately it confusing for me . I am not looking any code which download all the files, also this link is not for spreadsheet  , I need any method or service which just need to populate all spreadsheet name and ids so that user can just update by selecting any sheet name from dropdown . But thanks for your reply . Waiting from other developer for their view .

Comment: The link was just to show you how to create a drive service it was not intended for you to download the file.  I assumed you could put two and two together please check the last update.  I dont think you will get a better anwser from another developer as this is how the two apis work.  Sheets api cant give you a list of files on the users drive account thats what the google drive api is for.

Comment: I tried with suggested code by @Dalm but give exception : An exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Insufficient Permission [403]  .

Comment: You need to authenticate your user and make sure you have included one of the google drive scopes you must have consent of the user to access their drive data.  Check scope edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code provided by @DaImTo get all the necessary spreadsheet IDs on the Drive.

Then you may use `spreadsheets.get` method to get all the information on the particular spreadsheet including sheets names and ids https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Then you may use various methods from `spreadsheets.values` Resource to get/update/batchUpdate the values within the sheet. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values 
hint: putting only sheet name as a value for `range` parameter within `values.get` returns the range containing all the sheet values and it's quite convenient.

Comment: This is not my requirement , my requirement is to show all spreadsheet name in my drop-down . Not code is working , the piece of code with logic which you suggested is for specific spreadsheet that I already implemented . he link which has shared by @DaImT is confusing .

Comment: This link has been worked in my case . https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets

Comment: Exactly I was looking the same things .Thanks to all for your reply